# Can I use udev to control which kernel module is loaded for a device

Tags: kernel-modules, udev

I have 2 devices ([TM-S1000](https://epson.com/Support/Point-of-Sale/Check-Scanners/Epson-TM-S1000-Series/s/SPT_A41A266111) cheque scanner, [TM-70](https://epson.com/Support/Point-of-Sale/OmniLink-Printers/Epson-TM-T70-i-Series/s/SPT_C31C637786)/[TM-70II](https://epson.com/Support/Point-of-Sale/Thermal-Printers/Epson-TM-T70II-Series/s/SPT_C31CD38104) receipt printers) that I need to support. Unfortunately both of these devices have the same vendor and product ids: `04b8:0202` and the same modalias: `usb:v04B8p0202d0100dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFip02in00`

The only way to tell the difference is from the device provided `ID_MODEL`.

I would like to use the in-tree `usblp` module for the receipt printers, and the out-of-tree `usbtm` module for the cheque scanners.

Is there a way to control which kernel module is used by writing udev rules based on the `ID_MODEL`?